# Why is this if statement not outputting anything? (C++)

Tags: c++

The following program runs and outputs everything preceding the `if` statement. I do not know why the `if` statement is not outputting anything even though the expression is true.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "HeaderCh4-2.h"
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    my_info();
    int inch1, inch2, totalin, in2ft, remainderin;
    float meters, centimeters, miles;
    cout << "This program will perform several calculations on two distances, in inches, that you enter.\n\n";
    cout << "Please enter the first distance in inches:\t";
    cin >> inch1;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Please enter the second distance in inches:\t";
    cin >> inch2;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "\n\n";
    //output the two distances entered
    cout << inch1;
    cout << " in" << endl;
    cout << inch2;
    cout << " in" << endl;
    cout << "--------------\n\n";
    //calculate total distance in inches and the conversion from iches 
    to feet
    totalin = inch1 + inch2;
    in2ft = totalin / 12;
    remainderin = totalin % 12;
    cout << totalin << " in" << endl;
    cout << in2ft << " ft " << remainderin << " in\n\n" << endl;
    //conversion to metric
    meters = totalin * 0.0254;
    centimeters = totalin % (254 / 10000);
    cout << centimeters;
    if (totalin > 36)
    {
        float meters, centimeters;
        meters = totalin * 0.0254;
        centimeters = totalin % (254 / 10000);
        cout << "Metric conversion of " << totalin << " inches";
        cout << setw(10) << setprecision(1) << fixed << meters;
        cout <<
            setw(5) << left << " m";
        cout << setw(10) << setprecision(1) << fixed << centimeters;
        cout << setw(5) << left << " m";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Metric conversion of ??? is ???";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try adding a `\n` to the end of the strings.

Comment: What is your proof that "the expression is true"? Show your work.

Comment: What is in `HeaderCh4-2.h`? Because not all of your variables are declared in this code snippet

Comment: in the headerch4-2.h is                                                           
          #pragma once
          #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void my_info()
{
 cout << endl;

 cout << " Programmer: Kaleb" << endl;
 cout << " Course Name: Software Design & Programming I" << endl;
 cout << " Program name: Chapter 4 (program 2)" << endl;
 cout << " Instructor\'s Name: David Sylvester" << endl;
 cout << " Due date: 3-19-2019" << endl << endl;
}

Comment: `254/10000` is done using integer arithmetic, so has a result of zero.   `centimeters = totalin % (254 / 10000)` therefore involves division by zero.  Undefined behaviour.

Comment: When I compile the program it does output something that tells you what is wrong: Program received signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception in main () at main.cpp:49   centimeters = totalin % (254 / 10000);    Exactly what @Peter said.

Answer (score 1):

The following line in your code is not evaluated as expected (also pointed out in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55252791/why-is-this-if-statement-not-outputting-anything-c#comment97238069_55252791)) because it causes divide-by-zero resulting in Undefined Behavior:

```
centimeters = totalin % (254 / 10000); // (254 / 10000) = 0.0254 -> 0 (integer)
```

The modulus operator works only for integral types. You're using floating point values and expressions that yield floating point numbers. You need to use [std::fmod()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod) function from `<cmath>` header to calculate remainder for floats like this:

```
centimeters = std::fmod( totalin, (254.0f / 10000.0f) );
```